# AWS Amplify Auth.sendCustomChallengeAnswer issue

Tags: amazon-web-services, react-native, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I'm using a Custom-Challenge Authentication with AWS Amplify, Cognito, and React Native, implementing a Passwordless authentication process. The App was working ok, but for some reason after added a couple of new libraries just the authentication part stopped to work.

When I try to run this part:

```
 import {Auth} from 'aws-amplify';
 const user = await Auth.signIn(username); // This part its OK
 const signedUser = await Auth.sendCustomChallengeAnswer(user, confirmationCode); // This one breaks
```

The message I receive is this:
`TypeError: (0, _getRandomBase.default) is not a function`

A bit of more information about the project:

- "aws-amplify": "3.0.21",
- "aws-amplify-react-native": "4.2.2",
- "amazon-cognito-identity-js": "4.3.3",
- "@react-native-community/netinfo": "5.9.5",

My index.js file:

```
import Amplify from 'aws-amplify';
Amplify.configure({
  Auth: {...},
  API: {...},
  PushNotification: {...},
})
```

In Cognito I setup all the necessary Triggers like:

- CreateAuthChallenge, => This one is reached
- DefineAuthChallenge, => This one as well
- VerifyAuthChallenge, => This one is never reached!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I'm not sure what was the problem here, but after updating AWS Amplify to the latest version together with the rest of the libraries started to work.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error, and resolved it by updating the `amazon-cognito-identity-js` dependency.